# MacOS RemoteApp pixalated

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remoteapp

If I use RemoteApp on MacOS with the official Microsoft Remote Desktop on a Retina Display the application looks pixalated and way too big.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: What research have you done on this?  Also, this forum is for solving programming issues; you might try other StackExchange sites, like SuperUser, https://superuser.com/

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [apple.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Okay, I posted it now on Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393947/macos-remoteapp-pixalated. Thx for the tip!